# Night Light Clip In Cord Incandescent to LED & Safety

Tags: led, bulb

I have one of those seasonal villages that use a clip-in accessory cord with a night light bulb that inserts into a 1" opening. The bulb is suspended by a metal clip.

the standard incandescent 5W bulbs do not offer much life. They don't last as long as LEDS I am told. The above cord set-up cautions the use of 5W MAX Candelabra base UL bulbs. The plug has a built in 5 AMP, 125 volt fuse...

So here's my question(s):

Can I safety use a C7 .75 7W LED candelabra base bulb with 27 lumens of brightness? It fits perfectly and lights beautifully. However I am worried that it will not be safe. The replacement bulb says it is made for night lights. Will it be safe to use with the above cord description?

Thanks for fielding my question..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's safe.

I've done the same thing with several decorative accessories that use C7 night light bulbs.  Our items are turned on 24/7, the bulbs have been burning 3 years now.

Answer (score 0):

The whatever-that-thing-is is already using a night-light bulb, so the swap you propose is very appropriate.

I can't tell you the thing is safe, but it's certainly safer with an LED than an incandescent.  Incandescents make heat which can sometimes be trouble.

Comment: For what it's worth, LED C7's generate almost as much heat as the incandescent they replace.  Of course with the LED it's the driver rather than the heat/light generating filament.  When I converted 4 step lights (LED step lights weren't widely available yet) I used a thermistor / raspberry Pi setup to monitor before and after temps inside the single gang lampholder fixtures.  I also used Roscolux theater gel as you suggested recently on another question to correct the color, the only C7's available 3 years ago were horrible ice blue light.